# Pass By Value Instead Of Pass By Reference For Copy Paste Function

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, hashset, oracle-adf

I have an issues for pass by value in HashSet. Every time i would like to copy data from inside the table and paste the data on other page. But the problem i facing was it end up with pass by reference instead on pass by value. Which mean when i click 'Paste' button the data is the new 1 instead on old 1 that suppose saved in my hashset. Please advice how should i resolve this issues Thank you very much.Below is my code:

```
  static HashSet<ScmTelephoneDetailsViewRowImpl> copy_set = new HashSet<ScmTelephoneDetailsViewRowImpl>(); 

      public void copy_data(ActionEvent actionEvent){


    for(int z=0;z<scm_details_row.getRowCount();z++){

        ScmTelephoneDetailsViewRowImpl telephone_accounting_details_9 =(ScmTelephoneDetailsViewRowImpl)scm_details_row.getRowAtRangeIndex(z);
        copy_set.add(telephone_accounting_details_9);  

    }       
    System.out.println("copy_set " + copy_set.size()); 
    System.out.println("copy_set " + copy_set.getClass());       
}

public void paste_data(ActionEvent actionEvent){         

    System.out.println("Paste Data");
    Iterator setIterator =copy_set.iterator(); 
        while(setIterator.hasNext()){

         ScmTelephoneDetailsViewRowImpl get_interator = (ScmTelephoneDetailsViewRowImpl)setIterator.next();

            //System.out.println("copy_set "+ setIterator.next());           
            System.out.println("data inside "+ get_interator.getTelephoneUser());            
        }   

}
```

Comment: Explicitly copy the data where necessary...?

Comment: copy data from 1 table to other table in different page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java there is no way to pass by-reference types by value: you can do that only with primitive types and references themselves. When you want a copy semantic, you need to implement it yourself.

What's happening in your code is that you are making a shallow copy of your set:

```
for(int z=0;z<scm_details_row.getRowCount();z++){
    ScmTelephoneDetailsViewRowImpl telephone_accounting_details_9 =(ScmTelephoneDetailsViewRowImpl)scm_details_row.getRowAtRangeIndex(z);
    copy_set.add(telephone_accounting_details_9);
}
```

The loop above makes you a new collection, in the sense that if you add or remove anything from `copy_set`, the original `scm_details_row` is not going to see the difference. However, if you change any of your `ScmTelephoneDetailsViewRowImpl` objects, the objects in the original collection will change as well, because that's the same object.

To work around this problem, make a copy constructor or implement some sort of a "cloning" method for "deep" copying, and insert deep copies into the `copy_set`:

```
for(int z=0;z<scm_details_row.getRowCount();z++){
    ScmTelephoneDetailsViewRowImpl telephone_accounting_details_9 =
        (ScmTelephoneDetailsViewRowImpl)scm_details_row.getRowAtRangeIndex(z);
    ScmTelephoneDetailsViewRowImpl copyRow =
        new ScmTelephoneDetailsViewRowImpl(telephone_accounting_details_9);
    copy_set.add(copyRow);
}
```

In order for this to work you need to define a "copy constructor" for your `ScmTelephoneDetailsViewRowImpl` class:

```
public ScmTelephoneDetailsViewRowImpl(ScmTelephoneDetailsViewRowImpl other) {
    // Initialize this object using the data from the object "other" passed as the parameter
    this.someFieldOne = other.someFieldOne;
    this.someFieldTwo = other.someFieldTwo;
    // If there are collections in the object, make deep copies of them as well
    ...
}
```

Comment: This method didn't work:
ScmTelephoneDetailsViewRowImpl temp = new ScmTelephoneDetailsViewRowImpl(telephone_accounting_details_9)
am i miss up something?

Comment: @goh6319 Did you add a "copy constructor" that makes a deep copy? That's what the `ScmTelephoneDetailsViewRowImpl(ScmTelephoneDetailsViewRowImpl other)` is supposed to be. Please see the edit.

Comment: this method need to assign it 1 by 1. If my table have a lot of columns it will quite troublesome. Anyway, i still appreciated your suggestion. If i fail to figure out any method to do copy paste function. I will use your 1. ^^

Comment: I decide to use your way by create a new copy constructor. Just now i face some error issues is due to adf standard constructor didn't support customization. You need to create a new package and class instead to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly ScmTelephoneDetailsViewRowImpl is an object, and not a simple value.  But what I think you want is a new object, that is identical to the original object (all the fields are the same) but which occupies different memory.

Have you tied something like

```
ScmTelephoneDetailsViewRowImpl temp = telphone_accounting_details_9.clone();
copy_set.add(temp);
```

What you really want here is a deep copy.  which copies all the fields manually.

If your class ScmTelephoneDetailsViewRow is something you can extend or modify directly, then you could override the clone() function that inherits from Object.

REVISION:  in order to call clone() on your object it will need to implement the "interface" called Cloneable.  But there are no methods in that interface.  So you just need to add "implements Cloneable" to the class definition.  Assuming you control that class.

Another problem with the default implementation of clone() is that if your object contains any non-primitive fields, such as an array, than a copy of the pointer to the array will be made, it will not create a "deep" copy where it generates new array space and copies all the array elements too.   As I said earlier, you can overcome that if you @Override clone(), or make a new copy command of your own choosing.

Comment: Would you mind to explain in details how to do use clone function. Mine 1 have some error message such as Error(165,114):  clone() has protected access in java.lang.Object

Comment: There are good reasons to avoid `Object.clone()`. Please see [this post](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=71) for details.

Comment: Agreed, there are good reasons to avoid it in general.  Which is why I suggested the "new copy command".   I wasn't sure if he had access to the class source code, so I was trying to make due with what he might have.

Comment: @goh6319, Do you have access to the source code for the ScmTelphoneDetailsViewRowInmpl class?   If so, I think you should add a new method called "copyOf" or something like that.  Such a method could create a _new_instance_ of the STDVRI object, then load it up with the same fields before returning it.    The "clone() is protected" error means that your STDVRI class doesn't already implement clone(), and that method won't work for you (unless you can implement it yourself or just make the new method I described here.

Comment: @Teto, i have the access right to  ScmTelphoneDetailsViewRowInmpl class. That mean i can't use standard function need to create a new 1 like showing above.